# Bind a QTcpSocket to a specific port

Tags: port, qtcpsocket

I am connecting through a `QTcpSocket` to a `QTcpServer`. I can specify the listening port on the Server side, but the client chooses a random port for its connection. I have tried to use the method `QAbstractSocket::bind` but that made no difference.

Here is my code:

```c++
void ConnectionHandler::connectToServer() {
     this->socket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 2001);
     this->socket->connectToHost(this->ip, this->port);

     if (!this->socket->waitForConnected()) {
           this->socket->close();
           this->errorMsg = this->socket->errorString();
      }

     qDebug() << this->socket->localPort();
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reformulated your code into a [MCVE](/help/mcve):

```c++
#include <QDebug>
#include <QHostAddress>
#include <QTcpSocket>

#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<QTcpSocket> socket(new QTcpSocket);

    socket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 2001);
    qDebug() << socket->localPort(); // prints 2001

    socket->connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 25);
    qDebug() << socket->localPort(); // prints 0
}
```

Why does `connectToHost` reset the local port to 0?

This appears to be a bug in Qt.  In version 5.2.1, `QAbstractSocket::connectToHost` contains

```c++
d->state = UnconnectedState;
/* ... */
d->localPort = 0;
d->peerPort = 0;
```

In version 5.5, this has changed to

```c++
if (d->state != BoundState) {
    d->state = UnconnectedState;
    d->localPort = 0;
    d->localAddress.clear();
}
```

So it's likely that upgrading your Qt will fix the issue.